# How to conditionally declare the values of a datatype property based on another property in an ontology?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am developing an ontology to represent a crane. The basic structure is something like the one below.
[image]

Crane, component, different components and geometry are the main classes. the hasGeometry property connects a component to its geometric description class Geometry. As some of the crane components may or may not be present in each crane, I have added a datatype property isPresent, which takes Boolean (True/False) values. I want that the property hasGeometry only takes a value when the isPresent is 'True'. In other words, I want the component to have a geometric description only if it is present in the crane. Is there any way to put such conditional restriction in Protege?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to model this in Protégé the way you want. You could make Component a subclass of the intersection of Geometry with forall isPresent {true} and exist isPresent, but that won't necessarily be what you need. Do you need to explicitly represent missing components? It would be easier to only include components that are present

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ignazio . Yes, I agree that it would be easier to only include the components which are always present. However, some components are present occasionally, and they impact the geometry representation of the crane. So I wanted to keep them optional somehow and make the geometry dependent on their presence or absence.